# The maximum hard drive capacity for Intel 80286 based PC

Tags: hard-drive

I got myself an Intel 80286 based PC. It has 40Mb hard drive installed. What is the maximum hard drive capacity that this PC can handle?

Comment: Depends on which OS you install.

Comment: *why*! I hope you aren't using that for anything serious..

Comment: I once installed Vista on a 80286 with a 40mb hdd, and it run like lightning.

Comment: @Shutupsquare: Lol. Beginning with Vista, ACPI is a requirement.  No 80286 PC ever had ACPI, 40MB hard drive (which wouldn't even begin to hold 1% of Vista's files) and lack of MFM/RLL/ESDI drive support aside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hard to say exactly because the limit is partly BIOS based, but 504MB is a likely candidate.

Good article about the limits here:

http://web.inter.nl.net/hcc/J.Steunebrink/bioslim.htm